# Autocomplete not working for dynamic created input rows

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I have form with dynamic created rows. I added autocomplete with my form which worked fine for single row. But when I created dynamic rows, it stopped working. I attached main file, js file, backend file and jQuery online links of website which handle autocomplete for single row

```
<form method="POST">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-success" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
            <tr>
                <th width="15%"><center>Service</th>
                <th width="10%"><center>Mach No</th>
                <th width="10%"><center>Consultant</th> 
                <th width="5%"><center>Qty</th>                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="BtnAdd()">+</button>                          
                </th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="TBody">
           <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
               <td><input type="text"  class="scode form-control text-end" name="scode[]" id="tutorial_name"   onchange="GetDetail(this.closest('tr'))"></td>
               <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]" id="ccc" onfocus="Calc(this);"></td>
           </tr>
           // jQuery webfile for autocomplete
</form>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="frontend-script.js"></script>
```

Javascript code to add dynamic rows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /* Delete button */
    $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
    GetTotal();

    $("#TBody").find("tr").each(
        function(index)
        {
            $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
        }
    );
}
```

This is my backfile below which take values from the database table:

```
<?php

              include('database.php'); 

              $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM machine1 WHERE                            user_id LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'"; 
            $result = $conn->query($sql); 
             if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
               $tutorialData = array(); 
               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
                  $data['id']    = $row['id']; 
                  $data['value'] = $row['user_id'];
                   array_push($tutorialData, $data);
                 } 
                }
               echo json_encode($tutorialData);
?>
```

This is mine  js file

```
$(function() {
    $("#tutorial_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'backend-script.php'  
    });
});
```

Comment: @barmar sir please suggest if you here

Comment: Once you have added an input, you should again call `autocomplete` on it.

Comment: Having two id’s on the same page is not valid in html. So, you cannot just clone the input. You would also have to change the id.

Comment: can  u help in this reagrd by example,  i am very new in dynamic jquerry

Comment: Could do, but your code is incomplete it seems. What is ‘ #TRow’, for example?

Comment: its link with  this to add new row by clicking button <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="BtnAdd()">+</button>

Comment: Sure, but where can I find it in your code? There is no element with id ‘TRow’…

Comment: yes sir this code was missing am sorry :       <th width="15%"><center>Service</th>
            
   <th width="10%"><center>Consultant</th> 
   <th width="5%"><center>Qty</th>                       
   
                                                
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="BtnAdd()">+</button>
                          
                        </th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="TBody">
                      <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">

Comment: Anyway, I guess you will want to do something like `$(v).find("input").autocomplete()`.

Comment: yes i want my code should work, its my official assignment, i badly need help other wise wil lost job, can u make workable for  me if possible for u

Comment: You provide incomplete code that is not reproducable. So no-one can help you.

Comment: Except what I said: try `$(v).find("input").autocomplete()`

Comment: Put the file in a repository and share the link. I will have a look.

Comment: ok sir no issue

Comment: @Klaassiek this is the link of github  https://github.com/Umarrsp/abc1 where u can find project. Test.php is main file

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comments, you have to re-initialize the autocomplete feature every time you insert a new input. Simply call autocomplete on the new input every time you add one. Like this:

```
function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).find("input").autocomplete({
        source: 'backend-script.php'  
    });
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}
```

The first time you call autocomplete, jquery will check the inputs and add the autocomplete feature to the ones that are present on the page. When you add a new input, jquery is unaware of it being added. You will have to tell jquery to add it to the new input.

You will have to tweak the code above because now all the inputs on a new row have the autocomplete feature, which is not what you want. Give the name-input a specific class, like "the-name" and replace `find("input").autocomplete` with `find('.the-name').autocomplete`.

(Another thing: your input has an id attribute. Only one element with a specific id should be on the html page, otherwise your html is invalid. So, you should not clone an input with an id. Make it a class and everything will be fine.)

Comment: thanks alot sir! Its solved my problem. stay blessed